# Ordering of stationary subsets of a regular uncountable cardinal is transitive

Tags: set-theory

This comes from Jech Lemma 8.19 (page 99). 
If $\kappa$ is a regular uncountable cardinal, $A, B \subset \kappa$ are stationary subsets,

$$\begin{align}A<B 
&\iff A \cap \alpha \ \text{ is stationary for almost all } \alpha \in B\\ 
&\iff \exists \text{ closed unbounded }C: \forall \alpha , \alpha \in C\cap B \to A\cap \alpha \text{ stationary}\end{align}$$

The author leaves the following proposition as an exercise:
$$A<B \text{ and } B<C \implies A<C$$

I have tried proving this with no success. I picked clubs (closed unbounded sets) $C_{AB}$, $C_{BC}$ in $\kappa$ such that $\alpha \in B \cap C_{AB} \implies A \cap \alpha $ stationary, and $\alpha \in C \cap C_{BC} \implies \alpha \cap B$ stationary. The only reasonable thing to do next seems to take the intersection $C_{AC} = C_{AB} \cap C_{BC}$ which is also a club. I don't see how that helps.

Comment: I think considering $C_{AB}' \cap C_{BC}$ might work, where $C_{AB}'$ is the set of limit points of $C_{AB}$, which is also club.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\text{Lim}(C)$ be the set of limit points of $C$. If $C$ is a club, so is $\text{Lim}(C)$.

If $\alpha \in C \cap \text{Lim}(C_{AB}) \cap C_{BC}$, let $C_\alpha \subset \alpha $ be a club in $\alpha$, then, as $\alpha \in \text{Lim}(C_{AB})$, $\text{Lim}(C_\alpha) \cap C_{AB}$ is also a club in $\alpha$, so $\exists \beta \in B \cap \text{Lim}(C_\alpha) \cap C_{AB} $. Then $\beta \cap A$ is stationary, so as $C_\alpha \cap \beta$ is a club in $\beta$, $\exists \gamma \in C_{\alpha} \cap A$.

Hence $A \cap \alpha \subset \alpha$ is nonstationary.